# How to truncate a string to just 1 character C#

Tags: c#

Simple question: I only want the first letter of my string. How do I achieve that in `C#`?.

I have a really long work around using `IF` statements, but I'm sure there is a way to simply truncate it to 1.

In `vb.net` it seemed like

```
string q1s = q1l.Chars(1);
```

but that doesn't work in `c#`

Comment: Can you show your "really long workaround using IF statements" in C#, please? I can think of short expressions using one or two lines, and I'd be interested in seeing how you can use more than one `if` statement for that purpose.

Comment: its done by
if(q1l = "stringname")
{ string q1s = "d";
}

based on the fact I know what the string content will be.

Comment: @user3809554: How does that replicate any part of your VB.NET expression?

Comment: Please, save us the pain of reading your "workarounds" now and in the future. Take a class. Pick up book. Read The Fabulous Manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
string q1s = q1l.Substring(0, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

A string has an indexer. You can get any character from the string, not just the first:

```
string s = "Hello world"
char first = s[0];
```

You can then call first.ToString() if you really need it to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

myString[0]

blablabla, this is to reach 30 characters in my answer.

Comment: "Simple question, I only want the first letter of my string." This was the questions wasn't it? He didn't say it needed to be a string type Steve.

Comment: Well, it didn't 3 minutes ago. Including the time you posted your "Wrong" reply.

Comment: @Steve: Actually, the example from the question - `string q1s = q1l.Chars(1);` - does exactly that: It retrieves a single `char` and assigns it to a `string` (invoking an implicit conversion). The [`Chars` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the VB.NET way of accessing the indexer and returns a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

MyString[0] will return the 1st character in a string.